# Strange case statement in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

I have the following data

```
data A = C1 String | A :@: A
         deriving(Show)  

app inp = case inp of
     a1 :@: a2 -> (C1 "a") :@: (C1 "b")
     _         -> C1 "c"
```

Why does the case return the input instead of `(C1 "a") :@: (C1 "b")`?

```
*Test> app (C1 "c") :@: (C1 "d")
C1 "c" :@: C1 "d"
```

Works fine if i'll change `A :@: A` to `C2 A A`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function application has higher precedence than `:@:` (or any other infix operator), so `app (C1 "c") :@: (C1 "d")` is the same as `(app (C1 "c")) :@: (C1 "d")`, not `app ((C1 "c") :@: (C1 "d"))`. The latter does what you expect:

```
*Main> app ((C1 "c") :@@: (C1 "d"))
C1 "a" :@@: C1 "b"
```

A more idiomatic way of writing this is `app $ (C1 "c") :@: (C1 "d")`.